# Django login, logout urls and current user name

Tags: django, django-registration

I'm new to Django and just just got django-registration up and running. Could anyone tell me how to get a get a log-in, log-out url name and the name of the current user in my template. Are these called template tags? IS there a comprehensive list somewhere for all the default variables supplied with Django.

I'm a little lost with this. I've Googled for a while now but I couldn't find anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure that you have 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware' 
in `settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`

In template:

```
{{ request.user.username }}
```

The login and logout url can be found in settings:

- `settings.LOGIN_URL` (default=/accounts/login)
- `settings.LOGOUT_URL` (default=/accounts/logout)

You will have to implement those views and refer to it from `url` tag

{% url your.login.view.name %}

See..

- http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/
- http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings